# What are features we miss if we create a custom case object to replace standard case object?

Tags: case-object

we are planing to create a new custom case object instead of standard case object. Can some share me what are the features we  will miss from  standard case object and what are the  standard features which we can't implement through custom code.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. This question is likely to be too broad. Can you [edit] to identify specific features or functionality and ask a single question about those areas?

Comment: I would not go down this path at all; you lose out on tens if not hundreds of millions of dollars in the SFDC ecosystem R&D around Service Cloud

Answer (score 6):

## Web-to-Case

You can no longer create a simple HTML form and capture support requests. Can be replaced with Site.com or other integrations.

## Email-to-Case

You can no longer capture cases by email without code. Can be replaced with custom email handlers and code.

## Customer Service Portals

Your customers can no longer log cases in the portal, including viewing their tickets, uploading attachments, etc. Can be mostly replaced by Community logins, if I understand it correctly.

## Escalation Rules

You can no longer create escalation rules, which include possible reassignment and notification. Can be kind-of implemented with flows, etc, but will be very limited in capabilities.

## Auto-Response Rules

You can no longer automatically respond to Web-to-Case and Email-to-Case cases. Can be replaced with flows/workflows/etc but will be limited in capacity.

## Case Comments

Can no longer log comments in portals, have private comments, etc. Can be replaced with another custom object, but will have huge storage implications (2k per comment, instead of "free").

## Auto-Assignment Rules

Can no longer automatically route cases. Can use process/flows/etc but will have limited capacity.

## Case Assignment Notifications

Can no longer notify case owners on assignment. Can be done with workflow/process/etc, but will lose some functionality (the *option* to notify or not).

## Case Close Layout

Can no longer specify a separate page layout for closing a case. Can be implemented with custom code.

## Entitlements, SLA, Milestones

Can no longer use Entitlements, Milestones, and SLA features. Much of this can be implemented with custom code, but will require substantial effort.

## Case Teams

Cannot specify default case teams, affects sharing. Can be partially implemented in code.

## Account Protection

Cannot automatically block deletion of accounts when there are open cases. Can be implemented with code.

## Field Service

Cannot use Field Service features, as they require the use of cases.

## Omni-Channel

Cannot directly support Live Agent, call channel features, and other related customer support functionality. Most of this can be implemented through yet more code.

## Future Enhancements

Any new features that come out will not be available to you without implementing yet more code/workarounds.

## More (?)

This answer is already pretty long, but I'm pretty sure I've missed a few features. The main point is that you lose out on potentially a lot of features. Even if you don't want to use any of them now, the technical debt you'll acquire will be pretty significant. I would strongly advise you to reconsider using a custom object for the purpose of customer support. You will likely regret the decision in the long run.